# Why is filter_input returning NULL when the variables exist?

Tags: php, get, filter-input

I'm trying to retrieve some GET data and filter it to make sure it contains an integer. The url string is `events.php?id=22&month=2`, but when I try to get either variable `filter_input` returns `NULL` for some reason, I can't figure out why. This is my code:

```
if(!isset($pageId)) {
    $pageId = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FITER_VALIDATE_INT) ?: 4;
}
if(!isset($month)) {
    $month = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'month', FITER_VALIDATE_INT) ?: date('n');
    var_dump($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'month', FITER_VALIDATE_INT));
}
```

The `var_dump` returns `string(13) "id=22&month=2" NULL`. I've also tried `var_dump($_GET)` and get back `array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "22" ["month"]=> string(1) "2" }` as expected.

Why is the `filter_input` returning `NULL`? I've never had a problem retrieving `GET` data this way.

Comment: Your usage of ?: is pretty strange to me. What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: @Masiorama short hand ternary. For when you want the value in the `if` part of the ternary if truthy but don't want to re-type it. Same thing as `$var = 5 ? 5 : 0;` == `$var = 5 ?: 0;`.

Comment: Could you try with a ```var_dump($_GET)``` ?

Comment: @Masiorama if the `filter_input` returns `false` then use the value after `?:`. [This](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) explains how to use it quite well.

Comment: @tarini Already have, it also returns the values as expected. I'll add that to my question.

Comment: I knew short hand ternary but never guessed that omitting the actual value after ? could work to assign a value. Thanks guys :)

Comment: @Masiorama It only works if you're testing the variable you want to assign. It wouldn't work for `$var = ($v > 5) ? $v : 5` as an example.

Comment: @Styphon why not? It seems ok to me ... O_o. edit: sorry, we are OT here.

Comment: @Masiorama it would work, but what you get for the "value if true" part is the return value from the "if" part. And when I said "short hand ternary", I mean it is "shorter hand" for a ternary statement. The "wouldn't work" statement would return "true" if the statement was true. You wouldn't get the value of `$v` since your expression evaluates to boolean `true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FITER_VALIDATE_INT` should be `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT`. You are missing `L` in `FILTER` in all instances of the constant. Turning on error reporting would have thrown several `Notice: Use of undefined constant FITER_VALIDATE_INT - assumed 'FITER_VALIDATE_INT'` errors.

Comment: Argh! I hate it when it's a typo and you go so far as to post a question. Thank you.

Comment: @Styphon while in development, turn error reporting to `E_ALL`. It will save you a ton of headache.

Comment: I don't know why it's been turned off. It's on the development server so should have them all on, I guess a colleague disabled them. Someone's getting a kick in the ass.

Comment: Actually, I've just enabled errors using `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and an unrelated error did pop up, but not `Notice: Use of undefined constant FITER_VALIDATE_INT - assumed 'FITER_VALIDATE_INT'`, that's still not producing an error. No matter what I set it to (`-1` atm) it won't produce that error.

Comment: It's possible an error elsewhere is causing this error to not show (fatal error, try/catch). If you want to see the errors: [http://codepad.viper-7.com/uG5D31](http://codepad.viper-7.com/uG5D31). That's the only reason I found it, ran the code and saw the errors.